# Validation of Jasmine and Protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to automate the validation Protractor's intended use i.e. end to end or integration testing and Jasmine's intended use i.e. testing javascript code.
Would you pls suggest some pointers for the same.

Comment: http://www.guru99.com/protractor-testing.html
This might be helpful in setup

Comment: Thanks Sai Kiran, its helpfuI am looking for something which can help to validate protractor itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you checkout the tutorial.
http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial

Comment: Thanks HarlemSquirrel, will check.